# toast.cancel() doesn't seem to work

Tags: android, toast

I am trying to stop a toast message from appearing / stacking up while an instance is still shown on the screen. I press the "decrement button" and it is to reduce the quantity by 1, however if the quantity is equal to 1 a toast message appears. Now the problem is, each time I press the "decrement button" the toast messages keep stacking up. This is what I have tried and I am unsure of how to prevent the stacking up issue:

```
Toast toastMessage;    

...

public void decrementQty(View view) {
        if (quantity == 1) {
            if (toastMessage != null) {
                toastMessage.cancel();
            }
            toastMessage.makeText(this, "You must order at least 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        quantity -= 1;
        displayQuantity(quantity);
    }
```

Comment: When you need the Toast to be displayed ? When quantity is equal to 1 ?

Comment: I want the toast to be displayed when the quantity is 1 but each time the the decrement button is pressed while the quantity is at 1 the toast message keeps appearing. so if I have a user that presses it 50x the toast messages keep stacking up like a queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `else` branch

```
public void decrementQty(View view) {
        if (quantity == 1) {
            if (toastMessage != null) {
                toastMessage.cancel();
                toastMessage = null;
            } else {
               toastMessage = Toast.makeText(this, "You must order at least 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
               toastMessage.show();
            }
            return;
        }
        quantity -= 1;
        displayQuantity(quantity);
    }
```

Comment: I tried use an else, but if I press the"decrement button" say 50x the toast message stays on that much longer.

Comment: @davemib123 your code seems incorrect. You can't call `makeText` method on Toast object.